# Python Flask Install - Are these errors bad?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

When installing Flask I get errors but it still says successful. Are these errors going to cause problems for me?

Using Python3 on Debian 9

I tried upgrading setuptools, but still get the same errors.

```
Collecting flask
  Using cached Flask-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.21 (from flask)
  Using cached itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz
Collecting Werkzeug>=0.7 (from flask)
  Using cached Werkzeug-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting click>=2.0 (from flask)
  Using cached click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Jinja2>=2.4 (from flask)
  Using cached Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask)
  Using cached MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: itsdangerous, MarkupSafe
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for itsdangerous ... error
  Complete output from command /home/ev/Desktop/DNIT/venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-blrz3kyb/itsdangerous/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmprpoc62sipip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for itsdangerous
  Running setup.py clean for itsdangerous
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe ... error
  Complete output from command /home/ev/Desktop/DNIT/venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-blrz3kyb/MarkupSafe/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp8419jrrypip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for MarkupSafe
  Running setup.py clean for MarkupSafe
Failed to build itsdangerous MarkupSafe
Installing collected packages: itsdangerous, Werkzeug, click, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, flask
  Running setup.py install for itsdangerous ... done
  Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe ... done
Successfully installed Jinja2-2.10 MarkupSafe-1.0 Werkzeug-0.12.2 click-6.7 flask-0.12.2 itsdangerous-0.24
```

Comment: try to install the debian package `python-wheel` and retry your pip install flask command

Comment: As you use python3 you have to install python3-wheel.

Comment: Says it's all ready installed and using the latest version. Thank you though!

Comment: I apologize, that is indeed the correct answer. I had become overtired on another project. Thank you so very much! Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

this is how a solve the problem

```
pip install wheel
```

you can remove the venv folder and restart like this

```
python3 -m venv ./venv 

pip install wheel 
pip install flask
```

this will solve the problem